# From Shindig 2.0.2 to 2.5.1

Tags: apache-shindig

We were using Apache Shindig 2.0.2 and now need to update to version 2.5.1. However, the underlying code seems to have changed quite a bit (since some classes/methods are no longer available/moved?). I searched for a change/release log but to no avail. Do you know any document which helps with porting to Shindig 2.5.1 ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We do not have a document, that is the communities bad there.  I agree there are quite a few changes that may effect your upgrade.  If you have specific questions or need help the dev list is always willing to help you out.  dev@shindig.apache.org